# How to access var from ouside arrow function inside of it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with ar's (auto responses), so for example if I type in a channel "Hello how are you?" it will reply "Good, how are you?". I already a working system for creating ar's. I am using replit and it's inbuilt data base to try and achieve this, but I need to access the messages content inside of my function where I get the list of keys. Here is my current code:

```
    ARDB.list().then(keys => {
    for (var I=0; I<keys.length; I++) {
        if message.content == keys[I] {
          ARDB.get(Keys[I]).then(value => { 
            message.channel.send(value);
          });
        };
    };
});
```

The exact error is "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Any help would be appreciated but be aware I am relativity new to discord.js.

Comment: `if message.content == keys[I] {` is the problem `if (message.content == keys[I]) {` is the correct syntax

Comment: It apperars my days of other programming languages still have an effect on me today. Thank you for correcting my silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As Jaromanda X pointed out, "if message.content == keys[I] { is the problem if (message.content == keys[I]) { is the correct syntax".